# Relacionamento on-to-one em tabela auxiliar usando Laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent, modelo-relacional

Na aplicação que eu estou trabalhando o banco de dados está construído na parte de usuários, da seguinte maneira:

**user** `1 -------> 1` **user_address** `1 <-------- 1` **address**

Na tabela user não há uma coluna que referencie o endereço. O que existe é uma tabela auxiliar (que usamos normalmente para relações n pra n) com o user_id e o address_id em uma relação de 1 pra 1 tanto de user para user_address como de user_address para address. A argumentação do pessoal da infra é de que isso evitaria de existir um campo address_id direto na tabela user e esse ficasse em branco (pois o endereço não é de preenchimento obrigatório).

Ao dar início aos models me deparei com a seguinte situação: **Se, somente se**, a tabela user tivesse um relacionamento direto com a tabela address de um pra um, então no model de User eu somente precisaria colocar:

```
public function address(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

No entanto me ocorreu que se eu fizer isso com o model de user_adress eu não terei o address diretamente mas somente o address_id.

Utilizando o hasManyThrough eu poderia pegar o address dessa maneira (seguindo a documentação):

```
public function addresses(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\UserAddress', 'App\Address');
}
```

No entanto esse método retorna uma lista, e no meu caso, eu só teria sempre no máximo um registro.
Me restam disso tudo duas perguntas:

1. A forma como o banco de dados está construído é correta?
2. Qual maneira/método mais apropriada para recuperar o address do user de forma direta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não julgaria errado a forma como sua base de dados foi modelada. De fato, sua estrutura já está preparada para aceitar mais de um endereço por usuário e/ou vincular um endereço existente a um usuário diferente. No entanto, você precisaria pensar melhor no negócio ao invés de somente o código / a programação.

### O projeto sugere a possibilidade de cadastrar mais de um usuário em um mesmo endereço?

Apesar de isso ser uma realidade (as pessoas geralmente compartilham um mesmo endereço com pais, conjuges, repúblicas, etc), no mundo da tecnologia não costuma ser muito útil se ter uma opção de vincular mais de um usuário a um mesmo endereço. Se seu projeto está apto a chegar nesse ponto, mantenha essa estrutura a qualquer custo.

### O projeto sugere que um mesmo usuário possua mais de um endereço?

É comum projetos que exigem a possibilidade de endereços múltiplos. Um exemplo bem simples é o eCommerce. Você tem **a)** o endereço de cobrança e **b)** o endereço de entrega. Para uma segunda compra, talvez você não queira o mesmo endereço anterior, mas também não deseja removê-lo do sistema para que compras futuras sejam facilitadas. Excluíndo a possibilidade anterior, esse modelo adotaria uma relação **1 -> N** (1 usuário, N endereços) onde a estrutura seria melhor se você removesse a tabela do meio e mantivesse apenas a tabela **address**. Nela, você teria um **user_id** que resolveria seu problema.

### O projeto sugere que jamais um usuário poderá ter mais do que um endereço?

Nesse caso você pode optar por a) manter os dados do endereço dentro da tabela de usuário ou b) criar uma tabela complementar.

Quando o assunto é tabela complementar, as coisas podem complicar um pouco dependendo da forma como você decide trabalhar. Você pode, por exemplo, relacionar a coluna **id** da tabela **user** diretamente com a coluna **id** da tabela **address**. Dessa forma, se um usuário cadastrou um endereço, seu endereço estará no mesmo id que o próprio representa. Se o usuário não cadastrou, a numeração de seu id estará vazia na tabela **address**. Outra forma comum seria manter o mesmo padrão da questão anterior (1 -> N), mas limitar em código o cadastro de apenas um endereço.

Uma forma de alcançar isso é especificando na própria relação:

```
public function address(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Address')->first();
}
```

O método `first()` no relacionamento garantirá que você sempre carregará apenas um registro. Basta garantir que no momento da inserção, não haja registro para o usuário especificado.

---

Um complemento pessoal que sugiro é que jamais limite coisas triviais quando não há razão estrita para tal. É muito melhor você retornar uma lista de **endereços** e garantir que o Frontend percorra nem que seja por apenas 1 endereço do que criar uma limitação que no futuro possa exigir retrabalho de desfazer a limitação previamente criada. Dessa forma, se o frontend percorre pelo array com apenas 1 registro e no futuro o projeto decida aceitar mais de 1 endereço por usuário, seu código está preparado para tal. Basta retrabalhar a estilização/aparência.

Comment: Na verdade a entidade User é como um cadastro básico para a aplicação, existem outros relacionamentos para indicar se o cliente é Admin, Super, Vendedor e afins. Para alguns existem endereços e para outros não. Então para User o projeto sugere que sempre vai ser apenas UM endereço.

Comment: @touchmx nesse caso eu sugiro o caso 1 -> N ao invés da sua modelagem N <-> N. Você pode, depois, limitar como sugeri usando o `->first()` ou seguir minha segunda sugestão de nunca limitar e sempre possibilitar uma mudança futura com maior facilidade

Answer (score 2):

#### Consideração inicial

> A programação deve se adaptar ao banco, não o banco a programação, certamente o banco é mais constante do que a programação, pois envolve analise, e geralmente é 'modelado' pelo **DBA**, já o código qualquer um de seus colegas pode alterar.

#### Banco

- Quando eu monto um banco eu tendo pensas nas possibilidades e quase sempre evito usar relacionamento `1:1 <=> 1:1`, como você tem, o ideal seria `1:1`, pois evita ter tabelas extras assim como `JOIN`, `CONTRAINS`, `INDEX`, etc.
  Afinal de que adianta fazer um `INDEX` em `user` se `user_adresss` esta todo misturado?
- Separar os assunto é interessante, mas o exagero nunca é benéfico, não a problema nenhum um ter uma coluna com **NULL** no banco.

#### Relacionamento

Supondo as seguintes informações :

- Pessoa {nome, cpf, idade}
- Usuario {login, senha, admin::boolean}
- Endereco {endereco, bairro, num}
- Cargo {profissao, salario, carga_horaria}

Tipos de relacionamento :

- `1:1 <=> 1:1`
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- `1:1`
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual você acha que esta mais limpo?

#### Programação

Na programação a seria o mesmo `if`, verificar se tem na tabela auxiliar ou verificar se esta **NULL**.
Ja no *SELECT* muda :

- `1:1 <=> 1:1`

  ```
  SELECT
      *
  FROM
      pessoa p
      INNER JOIN pessoa_endereco pe ON pe.cd_pessoa = p.cd_pessoa
      INNER JOIN endereco e ON pe.cd_endereco = e.cd_endereco
  ```
- `1:1`

  ```
  SELECT
      *
  FROM
      pessoa p
      INNER JOIN endereco e ON p.cd_endereco = e.cd_endereco
  ```

Comment: Compartilho do mesmo pensamento que você Guilherme. Embora a sua consideração inicial seja logicamente válida, uma vez que o banco possuir algum 'problema' de organização, a programação tende a ser mais complexa. E isso impacta em tempo, manutenção e afins. Eu não dizer ainda qual seria a decisão do DBA nesse ponto. Mas suas explicações me ajudam a argumentar a respeito. Obrigado.